# Strange behavior with asynchronous program not running asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, threadpool

I printed which thread executes each called method in the following program and the results are very strange. I expected all asynchronous calls to be executed by a threadpool thread because @Jon Skeet mentioned that asynchronous calls use ThreadPool threads and that thread pool threads are background threads.

The thread id shows that the same thread that executes the Main method executes all called methods except for DisplayResult which is not an asynchronous method.

How is it that each call of DisplayResult, which is not an asynchronous method, is executed by a threadpool thread where as actual asynchronous methods when called are executed by a non-background thread, the same non-background thread that executed the Main method? And how many background threads and non-background threads should there be in this program?

```
public static async Task Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Main method: The thread executing this task is {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}, {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"And it is a background thread.");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("And it is a non-background thread");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a ThreadPoolThread");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a non-ThreadPoolThread");
            }

            Task task1 = ProcessReadWriteAsync(@"/tmp/temp1Write.txt");

            Task task2 = ProcessReadWriteAsync(@"/tmp/temp2Write.txt");

            await task1;
            await task2;
        }

        public static async Task ProcessReadWriteAsync(string filePath)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ProcessReadWriteAsync: The thread executing this task is {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}, {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"And it is a background thread.");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("And it is a non-background thread");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a ThreadPoolThread");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a non-ThreadPoolThread");
            }

            try
            {
            await ReadWriteAsync(filePath);

            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            } finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public static async Task ReadWriteAsync(string path, string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ReadWriteAsync 2 parameters: The thread executing this task is {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}, {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"And it is a background thread.");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("And it is a non-background thread");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a ThreadPoolThread");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a non-ThreadPoolThread");
            }

            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, 4096, useAsync: true);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];

                int noOfCharactersRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                DisplayResult(buffer: buffer);
        }

        public static async Task ReadWriteAsync(string path)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ReadWriteAsync 1 parameters: The thread executing this task is {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}, {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"And it is a background thread.");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("And it is a non-background thread");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a ThreadPoolThread");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a non-ThreadPoolThread");
            }

            await ReadWriteAsync(path, "");
        }

        private static void DisplayResult(byte[] buffer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"DisplayResult: The thread executing this method is {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}, {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"And it is a background thread.");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("And it is a non-background thread");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a ThreadPoolThread");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is a non-ThreadPoolThread");
            }

            string DecodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            string[] strings = DecodedText.Split('\n');

            for (int index = 0; index < strings.Length;index++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(strings[index]);
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
Main method: The thread executing this task is , 1
And it is a non-background thread

It is a non-ThreadPoolThread
ProcessReadWriteAsync: The thread executing this task is , 1
And it is a non-background thread

It is a non-ThreadPoolThread
ReadWriteAsync 1 parameters: The thread executing this task is , 1
And it is a non-background thread

It is a non-ThreadPoolThread
ReadWriteAsync 2 parameters: The thread executing this task is , 1
And it is a non-background thread

It is a non-ThreadPoolThread
ProcessReadWriteAsync: The thread executing this task is , 1
And it is a non-background thread

It is a non-ThreadPoolThread
ReadWriteAsync 1 parameters: The thread executing this task is , 1
And it is a non-background thread

It is a non-ThreadPoolThread
ReadWriteAsync 2 parameters: The thread executing this task is , 1
And it is a non-background thread

It is a non-ThreadPoolThread
DisplayResult: The thread executing this method is , 4
And it is a background thread.

It is a ThreadPoolThread
1. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
2. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
3. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
4. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
5. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
6. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
7. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
8. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
9. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
10. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
11. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
12. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
13. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
14. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
15. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
16. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
17. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
18. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
19. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
20. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
21. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
22. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
23. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
24. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
25. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
26. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
27. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
28. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
29. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
30. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
31. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
32. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
33. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
34. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
35. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
36. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
37. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
38. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
39. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
40. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
41. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
42. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
43. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
44. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
45. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
46. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
47. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
48. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
49. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
50. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
51. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
52. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
53. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
54. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
55. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
56. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
57. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
58. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
59. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
60. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
61. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
62. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
63. msdn.microsoft.c

DisplayResult: The thread executing this method is , 5
And it is a background thread.

It is a ThreadPoolThread
1. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
2. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
3. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
4. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
5. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
6. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
7. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
8. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
9. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
10. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
11. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
12. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
13. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
14. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
15. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
16. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
17. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
18. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
19. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
20. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
21. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
22. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
23. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
24. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
25. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
26. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
27. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
28. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
29. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
30. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
31. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
32. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
33. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
34. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
35. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
36. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
37. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
38. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
39. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
40. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
41. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
42. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
43. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
44. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
45. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
46. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
47. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
48. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
49. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
50. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
51. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
52. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
53. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
54. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
55. msdn.microsoft.com                                     42972
56. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff730837.aspx               146159
57. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx                83732
58. msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa578028.aspx               205273
59. msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj155761.aspx                29019
60. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh290140.aspx               117152
61. msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh524395.aspx                68959
62. msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms404677.aspx               197325
63. msdn.microsoft.c
```

Comment: "public static async Task Main()" is more of a syntax sugar to enable await in Main method, so its execution can be different from your expectation (like your code observed).

Comment: Ignore `async`. Ignore any thoughts about threads. Read your code as if it's single-threaded and entirely normal, right up until you hit an `await` and whatever is to the right of that has been evaluated to produce a `Task` (that includes entering any method calls to the right of it). Congratulations, that's exactly what happens. How far do you get in your chain of method calls before you hit that first `await`?

Comment: `I expected all asynchronous calls to be executed by a threadpool thread because @Jon Skeet mentioned that asynchronous calls use ThreadPool threads` this is absolutely false. I doubt Jon Skeet actually said this because it is not correct, but if he did, please link to the question/answer so it can be corrected. It's very simple, if you're not using `Task.Run()` with asynchronous calls, you're not using threadpool threads. Everything is running on one thread. Unless of course, the async method doesn't respect API etiquette and calls `Task.Run()` or spawns other threads in the implementation.

Comment: I removed some non-essential parts from the question. @Damien_The_Unbeliever. What do you mean by chaining of method calls? My understanding of a method call chain is `doSomethingOne().doSomethingTwo.doSomethingThree` etc.

Comment: I mean a calls b calls c...

Comment: @PatrickTucci I couldn't find it but I did find [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netframework-4.8#remarks "First bullet point")

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You make it sound like when `Main` calls `ProcessReadWriteAsync` you hit the first `await` in the try block of `ProcessReadWriteAsync` but I believe that you would hit the first `await` in `Main` at the statement `await task1;` not in `ProcessReadWriteAsync`.

Comment: @PatrickTucci Statements such as "Note that the thread pool isn't just used for whatever asynchronous calls you make" and "This is a good reason to avoid using the thread pool for particularly long-running tasks" imply that asynchronous calls use thread pool threads by default [link](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/threadpool.html "Jon Skeet blog")

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia this is not an MSDN article for `Task`. It is an article for `Threadpool`. When you spawn a `Task` using the `Threadpool`, such as by using `Task.Run()`, you are scheduling the work to run on the threadpool.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia this is only true when using the `Threadpool`. Using the `Threadpool` is not the same thing as awaiting an asynchronous method call. You can run asynchronous methods on the `Threadpool` using `Task.Run()`, but that is NOT the default.

Comment: @PatrickTucci when I read that MSDN article I misunderstood it as meaning that when you spawn a `Task` by calling an asynchronous method you are scheduling work to run on the thread pool. Thanks for clearing up my misunderstanding.

Comment: You don't *spawn tasks* by calling async methods at all. From the caller's perspective, it's entirely a normal method call. From the callee's perspective, it's entirely a normal mathod call, *until* it `await`s.

Comment: @PatrickTucci so when you call an asynchronous method, the default is for it to run on a non-background thread? So then how is it that `Task`s that are started without being awaited executed in parallel (hence the interleaving results) if one non-background thread is executing those `Task`s?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are correct, that was my mistake. I can't edit my comment, but it should read _When you run an asynchronous method on the `Threadpool`_.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, @MyWrathAcademia, but I'd suggest you approach the comments/answers as if you've never heard anything about async/await, rather than thinking you mostly understand it but just need a few details clarified. There are many misconceptions here.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia because there is inherent waiting involved with I/O bound code. When your code requests bytes from a file, it can do other things while it's waiting, like attempt to read from another file, even without a second thread. These articles from [Eric Lippert (an old article about C# 5.0 CTP, but still a good read)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/october/asynchronous-programming-easier-asynchronous-programming-with-the-new-visual-studio-async-ctp) and [Steven Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) are must-reads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All asynchronous methods start running on the current thread. Nothing different happens until you hit an `await` that acts on an incomplete `Task`. But whatever you're feeding to `await` has to actually return a value (a `Task`) before `await` actually does anything.

So lets walk through exactly what's happening:

1. `Main` runs until it calls `ProcessReadWriteAsync(@"/tmp/temp1Write.txt")`
2. `ProcessReadWriteAsync(string)` runs until it calls `ReadWriteAsync(filePath)`
3. `ReadWriteAsync(string)` runs until it calls `ReadWriteAsync(path, "")`
4. `ReadWriteAsync(string,string)` runs until it calls `stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)`
5. `stream.ReadAsync()` does some magic until it returns an incomplete `Task`
6. The `await` in `ReadWriteAsync(string,string)` see that incomplete `Task` and *returns* a new incomplete `Task`, with the rest of the method signed up as a continuation of that `Task`
7. `ReadWriteAsync(string)` returns an incomplete `Task`
8. `ProcessReadWriteAsync(string)` returns an incomplete `Task`
9. There is no `await` yet in `Main()`, so execution continues there.
10. `Main()` calls `ProcessReadWriteAsync(@"/tmp/temp2Write.txt")`, which starts that whole process again.

All of that happens on the same thread.

When you finally call `await task1`, it tells it to pause execution until the `Task` is completed. At this point, none of your code is running anymore.

When `stream.ReadAsync()` finally completes, its `Task` is set to `Completed` and the rest of `ReadWriteAsync(string,string)` runs until completion, which then triggers `ReadWriteAsync(string)` to run to completion, which then triggers `ProcessReadWriteAsync(string)` to run to completion. All of this happens on a background thread, which is why you see `DisplayResult` running on a background thread.

Once `task1` is set to completed, your `Main()` method resumes.

Keep in mind that in an application with a synchronization context, like a UI application or ASP.NET (not Core), the continuations do not happen on a background thread. They will happen on the same thread they started on. So in those cases, the continuations would not even start until you hit `await task1`. However, you can tell it that you don't need them to return to the same synchronization context with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Async is much clearer now, thanks. When is an incomplete `Task` returned? Is it the instant a TaskResult returning async method is called? Is an incomplete `Task` a `Task` that returns a TaskResult - is that why only `stream.ReadAsync` returns an incomplete Task since all other Async methods that are called return only `Task`?

Comment: And `await` acting on the incomplete `Task` returned by `stream.ReadAsync` causes a return up through the frames `ReadWriteAsync(string, string)`, `ReadWriteAsync(string)`, `ProcessReadWriteAsync(string)` of the function call stack (i.e. last in first out), just like in recursion? Why does the rest of the code in the methods run to completion on a background thread? Is it an arbitrary decision or is there a specific reason for the remaining code in the suspended methods not to run on a non-background thread?

Comment: *"When is an incomplete Task returned?"* - When `stream.ReadAsync()` returns one. A truly asynchronous method (one that makes an I/O operation and pauses code execution until it's done) actually *returns* an object that inherits from `Task`. The simplest example of this is if you look at [the code for `Task.Delay()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5863) - it returns a [`DelayPromise`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5905) object, which inherits from `Task<>`.

Comment: *"Why does the rest of the code in the methods run to completion on a background thread?"* - Because it will complete faster that way (it doesn't have to wait for the original thread to be freed up) and there is no reason not to. However, in a UI application, where you can only modify the UI from a single thread, there is a reason to resume execution on the thread that it started on, which is why it works different there. A console application does not have that restriction.

Comment: Those links are immensely useful. So an async method runs until the return command which returns a promise named <AsyncMethodNamePromise> and it is that promise that represents the incomplete `Task`?

Comment: The promise encapsulates the return value and handles the logic for implementing (i.e. carrying out) the `Task` and at line [5942](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5942), after the `Task` (i.e. the timer) is completed, the promise [sets the result of the `Task<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.trysetresult?view=netframework-4.8) (i.e. the return value of `Task.Delay`) as `VoidTaskResult`.

Comment: In other words, a promise is returned by an Async method and that promise has the authority to do (i.e. complete) the `Task` for that particular Async method.

Comment: At the line [5896](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5896) the start time for the invocation of the method `Complete()` for (i.e. of) this timer passed as the first argument to the constructor is set to the value of `millisecondsDelay` (in other words, `DelayPromise.Complete()` is invoked after the amount of time specified by `millisecondsDelay`), the `Timer` instance is then assigned to the internal field `promise.Timer`.

Comment: After the due time, or in other words the start time (i.e. `millisecondsDelay`) expires `DelayPromise.Complete()` is invoked, if the `Task` has not been cancelled `succeeded = TrySetResult(default(VoidTaskResult))` attempts to transition the incomplete `Task<VoidTaskResult>` into the RanToCompletion state by setting a value for the type parameter `<>`,

Comment: or in other words, when a value (such as the `default` value of the internal struct `VoidTaskResult`) is set as the result of a `Task` (i.e. `Task<TResult>`) that `Task<TResult>` is marked as ran to completion, `true` is returned and the boolean variable `succeeded` becomes `true`. This also shows that an incomplete `Task` is not a `Task` that returns a result, all `Task`s return a result whether `Task` or `Task<TResult>`, the former just returns `VoidTaskResult`.

Comment: An incomplete `Task` is a proxy task (i.e. a promise) that has the authority to implement the assigned task and has not transitioned the (underlying) `Task<TResult>` into the RanToCompletion state.

Comment: If in a UI application the continuations happen on the current thread then would it not tie up the UI thread? [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/using-async-for-file-access#parallel-asynchronous-io) says *"The advantages of asynchrony are that it doesn’t tie up multiple threads, and that it doesn’t tie up the user interface thread."*. From your breakdown I can see how asynchrony doesn't tie up multiple threads, however in a UI app I can't see how asynchrony does not tie up the UI thread if continuation runs on the same thread they started on?

Comment: It's because the *waiting* doesn't happen on the UI thread. Actually, if it's asynchronous, [the waiting happens nowhere](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). You want the continuation to run on the UI thread because you are likely planning to update the UI with the results of whatever you were waiting for, and UI updates can only happen on the UI thread. But if you have to run some CPU-intensive code, it's a good idea to move that to another thread - something you have to take care of yourself.

Comment: *"because the waiting doesn't happen on the UI thread"* I don't understand what this (i.e. "the waiting") means. Assuming the UI thread to be the thread that launches the UI application I imagined it to be like the thread that starts the program by running the Main method at step 1, so the UI thread just like this thread, does the waiting at step 6 when the `await` encounters an incomplete `Task` or may be the *"waiting"* is done when you call `await task1`? Can you clarify, may be using the code in my question as an example (i.e. making an analogy using my question's code)?

Comment: After reading the [link](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) you sent and the part *”which returns an incomplete task to the button click event handler, which suspends the async method, and the UI thread continues executing.”* I think you mean that the UI thread does not `await myDevice.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.length);`,

Comment: so the UI thread does not block, just waiting for that operation to complete which means that the UI thread is not “tied up” and is ready to do the continuations, is this right? And for a UI application the continuation of the method that runs until an `await` sees an incomplete `Task` is queued onto the UI context, and the UI thread will resume (i.e. continue) executing that method when it gets around to it?

Comment: I think you're getting it now :) For further reading, Microsoft has some very well written articles about [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). The illustration of cooking is a good one to help understand this. That article is just the first article in the series. Look in the left panel and you'll see more under that heading.

Comment: Thanks, If I could upvote your answer a million times I would. I want to understand asynchronous programming intuitively so I just have a few more things to clear up. Does asynchrony mean that a new thread processes an operation if that operation cannot be completed immediately (i.e. indicated by an incomplete `Task`) which explains why `stream.ReadAsync` finally completing and the continuations of `ReadWriteAsync(string, string)`, `ReadWriteAsync(string)`, and `ProcessReadWriteAsync(string)` all happen on a background thread?

Comment: If so I want to clarify, after `ReadAsync` returns an incomplete `Task` in step 5 is it a background thread that completes that incomplete `Task`? I can't test this with print statements since I don't have access to where `FileStream.ReadAsync()`is defined. Also can you confirm when exactly the background thread starts, is it when the `await` starts returning incomplete tasks at step 6 or at step 9 when the first thread (i.e. non-background thread) continues execution in `Main()?`

Comment: In the example I gave, all of steps 1 to 10 happen on the same thread, one after the other. The "continuations" of the tasks is what happens after the waiting is done. In your example where you're reading a file, that is after Windows receives the data from the hard drive. When that happens, all of your code after `await stream.ReadAsync()` starts running on a background thread. That's why you see `DisplayResult()` running on a background thread. (and remember that it runs on a background thread only because there is no synchronization context)